# Two-step cluster analysis in Python

Tags: cluster-analysis, cluster-computing

I'm trying to conduct a two step cluster analysis. I studied some resources and code like this. Can you please suggest me anything to improve this code?

Here, first I used K-means clustering. Then I added the labels from K-Means clusters to my data frame. then I see the centroid connections of the cluster labels in a hierarchical order in a dendrogram. Then I applied second phase of the clustering.

Confusion 1: my dataset us huge by elbow method shows to use less than 10 clusters in the first step at k-means, when I used two or three clusters I got best silhouette scores. so I used 5 clusters in k-means, my silhouette score were 0.59, then I created another 3 clusters in agglomerative. my clusters are not in a good shape.

Can you please check the codes?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the CSV file
data = pd.read_csv('Socio-hpms.csv')
data.head(10)


# Step 1: KMeans Clustering
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4, random_state=42)
kmeans.fit(data)
labels = kmeans.labels_

# Optional: Plot KMeans result
plt.scatter(X_scaled[:, 0], X_scaled[:, 1], c=labels, s=50, cmap='viridis')
plt.title("KMeans Clustering")
plt.show()

## Add the K-Means labels to the dataframe
data.insert((data.shape[1]),'kmeans_data_cluster',kmeans_data_cluster)

# Step 2: Hierarchical Clustering
# For hierarchical clustering, we use the centroids from KMeans as inputs
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_

# see the dendogram of your k-means clusters labels by centers
linkage_matrix = linkage(centroids, method='ward')

# Plot the dendrogram
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
plt.title('Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram (Centroids)')
dendrogram(linkage_matrix, above_threshold_color='y', orientation='top')
plt.show()


# Now use agglomerative clustering
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering 

hc = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = 3, affinity = 'euclidean', linkage ='ward')

y_hc = hc.fit_predict(data)
```